# Paint for a Doorway Threshold?

Tags: painting, exterior, repainting

What is a decent paint for a doorway threshold for a main exterior door that can stand up to the high traffic? I recently painted a covered front porch and used Behr Premium Floor and Porch low luster enamel and it has seemed to hold up well, although this porch doesn't get a lot of use. This threshold I am painting will get higher traffic daily.

The threshold is brand new, so I was going to first prime with an oil based prime, and then follow up with 2 coats of paint. The exterior is dark grey composite, and inside will be a medium gray luxury vinyl, so I think a dark grey paint should fit in well.

I could consider staining and then putting polyurethane coats on, but since this threshold will be mated to grey composite, and grey vinyl I am guessing the stain will be hard to match nicely and paint may just look better, but I'm open to stain suggestions too.

I can buy from Home Depot/Lowes, Sherwin Williams, or Benjamin Moore. Am I looking for an enamel that is specific for porch and floor? Is there a different paint/product I should be considering instead?

Comment: Since repeated footsteps grinds down stone steps then a paint coating will never hold up long - depends on your definition of long though 5 minutes or 5 decades.

Comment: might consider going over the other-wise-finished result with a can of clear matte spray acrylic. It's forms a massive single-molecule water and UV-proof coating that prevents fade and erosion and will take harsh cleaners a lot better than regular paint when/if it does need cleaning. Also great for kid's areas...

Answer (score 3):

If you're OK with the smell and clean-up of alkyds (“oil”), stick with them for the topcoat.  No latex will perform as well.

In California-like states, they have an intentional loophole allowing alkyd paints for architectural use, as long as you buy it in quarts.

We don't do shopping advice on this platform, but I will say a lot of shops are ill equipped to custom mix alkyds.  Sherwin can handle it in their commercial stores no problem, their lines go all the way up to "totally bonkers" 2-part LPU in case you have a jetliner to paint. Their "out in the neighborhoods" stores that sell only architectural paint may not know what alkyd is.  Welcome to buying real paint!

Comment: Thanks @harper. Can you break it down a bit further on the type of alkyds? I called Sherwin and the guy didn't really have much advice other than Emerald Urethane trim paint which didn't see accurate to me. I also see they sell a specific Porch and Floor Enamel but it is a latex product and the guy said they don't sell a lot of it so he wasn't sure how good it was.

Comment: @RocketManZ that's not an alkyd paint, it's yet another attempt at an alkyd substitute. A local hardware store tried to shove that on me a few years ago. Talk to a Sherwin or other maker commercial store.